# Change network card behaviour upon sleep Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, sleep

Where would one adjust whether network card goes to sleep when computer enters sleep in Windows 7?

I have two very similar computers(both C2Ds about 4 years old), both have hybrid sleep option turned on. However, one shuts down network connection upon sleep (light goes out on network card) but other one does not (light stays on).

I would like to make the network card power down on the second computer when entering sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Open device manager, right click on the adapter and select properties. In there will be power options which may give you the option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a well presented answer! This was a very good try, however, both network adapters have the "Allow to turn off" option checked. One is Realtek(turns off), one is Atheros(doesn't). Maybe, I should see if motherboard drivers are all working.

Comment: No problem - please mark as answer if it was the answer :)